# Firestore, I would like to import the timestamp type data on a monthly basis

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore, I would like to import the timestamp type data on a monthly basis.

I wanna show my data by month divider.
So, i think i have to get data by month.

now, i've tried query by using startAt, endAt.
but it's not easy.
could give me a hint ?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you struggle on importing data or reading them in a way such that you can output the month divider simply?

Comment: oh, sorry. I've struggled in reading date and printing the month by divider.